# jquery hiding divs based on query results

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page in which a query is run to see if a caller has forwarding enabled.  The result page is a form that the user can use to make changes to his call forwarding if he chooses.  the results from the query are either yes or no, and if yes, the forwarded to number.  I am using jquery to hide the cfaDesc div if he selects the "disabled" radio button, that works great.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$("div.cfaDesc").hide();
$("input[name$='cfa']").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).val();
    $("div.cfaDesc").hide();
    $("#" + test).slideDown('slow');
});
});
```

my problem is the initial query.  If he has it enabled, I need to show the cfaDesc div. with the above query, no matter what the result is, it will be hidden.  I am not sure how to change the hide/show attribute based on the query that is run before this code.

Comment: can you show us ur fiddle

Comment: i havent used fiddle before.  let me try....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K3jrK/

Comment: as you can see in fiddle,  the radio button is "CHECKED" because of previous sql query.  if you click disable/enable it works fine.  I need the input text field to show up on initial load, because the field is checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just trigger the click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='cfa']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.cfaDesc").hide();
        $("#" + test).slideDown('slow');
    }).click(); // this line trigger the click event
});
```

I'm not sure if it is exactly what you need, your question was not clear to me. This solution will slideDown some panel if it is already defined in your "cfa" input.

Comment: You will trigger click event for all radio buttons instead of first.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.cfaDesc").hide();
    $("input[name$='cfa']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.cfaDesc").hide();
        $("#" + test).slideDown('slow');
    })

    $("input[name$='cfa']:enabled").first().click();
});
```

[View Example](http://jsfiddle.net/z7qvC/1/)

Comment: the problem with this Valery is that if you move the "CHECKED" attribute to the disable radio button and run the script again, it still has it enabled.

Comment: @bart2puck I added ':enabled' selector to example.